# How to remove apply button in Views Exposed Filter

Tags: php, drupal-7

In my drupal 7 site I want to remove an apply button in form I created in Views (Exposed form in block = Yes).
I tried this in my template.php:

```
function myproject_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$vars, $hook) {
    dpm($vars);
    if ($vars['form']['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-search-page') {
        // Remove the submit button ??
        unset($vars['form']['submit']);

    }
}
```

... but that does not work. Can any one point me in the right direction?
//Tommy
 EDITED:
I now succeeded in removing the button, with this snippet:

```
function myproject_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-search-page') {
    // submit on enter

    // Remove the submit button ??
    unset($form['submit']);

    }
}
```

... so what I need now is how to submit the form on enter. I keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

For drupal 8 peeps, here is how to hide the button:

```
function template_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-products-page-1') {

      // Remove the submit button
      unset($form['actions']['submit']);

  }
}
```

Comment: you could replace `$form['#id']`by `$form_id`:  `if ($form_id == 'views-exposed-form-products-page-1') { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I complicated this too much. Just hiding the button with CSS with:

> .views-submit-button{     display:none; }

... and everything worked as it was supposed to.